# ffmpeg- drawtext style- bold, italics, underline

Tags: ffmpeg

How can we specify style in drawtext filter. Example, draw 'Hello' in a regular font, but it should be bold, in italics and underlined. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this answer is late, but, from the FFMPEG documentation: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html

> Use fontconfig to set the font. Note that the colons need to be
>   escaped.

```
drawtext='fontfile=Linux Libertine O-40\:style=Semibold:text=FFmpeg'
```

You have to configure the **fontconfig** file of course, set up your **desired fonts** (be careful to have all the styles that you need) in the fonts location and then run the drawtext with the font family name followed by '*:style=*'.

Example:

```
-vf "drawtext='fontfile=DejaVuSans\:style=ExtraLight:text=FFmpeg'"
```

This worked for me in the console and as a php shell exec command. You can use whatever font style, as long as (for the style and font family that you chose), there's a font file in the font directory that follows this rule: *FontFamilyName*-*StyleName* .
I really hope that this helps!

Comment: Note also the `drawtext` parameters are all surrounded by single quotes. This matters. For me, the equivalent of `-vf "drawtext='fontfile…\:style…'"` works,  `-vf "drawtext=fontfile…\:style…"` fails,  `-vf "drawtext=fontfile…\\:style…"` fails, but `-vf "drawtext=fontfile…\\\\:style…"` works again.  Also, it looks like the **fontconfig** keywords may only appear in the **fontfile=** value, not in another value like **font=** .

Comment: It doesn't work for me: "Option 'style' not found"

Comment: @JavaRunner, I had the same `[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x7fd5f6706340] Option 'style' not found`, the issue was I forgot to put the `'` in the right places. See the comment above yours, compare it to your command carefully.

Comment: How to use "underline" it never works for me, I managed to use italic or bold but not unserline

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the target font:

```
drawtext= fontfile=fonts/path/Arial-Bold.ttf :text=FFmpeg
```

The font family should have proper file for every style you want to use.